# Can Gnar jump multiple times?

Tags: league-of-legends

The new champion Gnar has been released on PBE, and one of is skills is a jump.

According to the champion page,

> Gnar jumps in a target direction and gains a moderate attack speed boost. If Gnar lands on a unit, he bounces, hopping again in the same direction. If Gnar hops onto an enemy unit, he also damages and slows them.

If he continues to land on units, does he continue to hop, or would he stop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gnar can only gain 1 extra jump from his E when landing on a unit. Please note that only minions, monsters, pets and champions count as units. **Turrets, Wards and similar objects like Jarvans Flag don't work**.

If you bounce off it's basically the same spell just applied a second time. You have the same range and the same damage as your initial cast.

Comment: What happens if he lands on a unit again with his second jump?

Comment: Was on reddit and learned that, according to rioters, until fairly recently, he could bounce continuously, but they found it was causing too many unintentional tower dives.
So now its just one

Answer (score -1):

1 extra jump is not a good way of saying it. If you look at [the reveal video page for Gnar,](http://eune.leagueoflegends.com/en/champion-reveal/gnar-the-missing-link) it's misleading to say an extra jump. You will not be able to control the second jump, so I would say it's more like you bounce.

If he lands on a champion or minion, he will hop again in the same direction that he was already hopping. This functions much like a Heimerdinger bouncing bomb when used with his ult.

You won't be able to control it, but you'll be able to cover a good distance if you need to go far in a certain direction.